# Unable to install packages after R update: unable to access index for repository: internet routines cannot be loaded

Tags: r, repository, install.packages

I use RStudio, and I updated R yesterday to the following version:

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24) -- "Arbor Day"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Now, I can't connect to any CRAN mirrors (I've tried 4 different ones) or install packages. When I start RStudio, I get the following errors on start up:

```
Error in tools::startDynamicHelp() : internet routines cannot be loaded
Warning: namespace ‘lme4’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘lmer1’
Warning: namespace ‘ggplot2’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘plot1’
Warning: namespace ‘emmeans’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘.Last.ref_grid’
Warning: namespace ‘pbkrtest’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘.Last.ref_grid’
[Workspace loaded from C:/Users/xxx.RData]

Loading required package: lmerTest
Loading required package: lme4
Loading required package: Matrix
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lme4’:
 package ‘lme4’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
Failed with error:  ‘package ‘lme4’ could not be loaded’
```

Then, when I try to install a package, I get the following message:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxx/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  internet routines cannot be loaded
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 4.0.0)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
  internet routines cannot be loaded
```

I know there are multiple threads on these warnings, but I haven't found a solution to this problem on any of them.
Things I've tried already that haven't worked:

- changing the CRAN mirror setting - I've tried 4 different ones, and the mirrors are working because it works on another computer
- restarting the program
- restarting the computer
- changing the setting in Tools>Global options>Packages so that https is unchecked
- updating RStudio (though it is also a problem in R as well)
- uninstalling and reinstalling R 4.0
- checking the library path - seems correct
- making Internet Explorer the default browser
- running the command `options(repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')`
- running the command line `install.packages("package name", dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')`
- running the command `options(download.file.method="libcurl")`
- running the command `Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")`

My partner downloaded R 4.0 and RStudio on to his computer and it works fine.

Any suggestions? I'm new to Stack Overflow and pretty new to R, so please, step by step instructions/suggestions where possible!

Comment: Did you check if your antivirus was blocking the connection from RStudio? Run httr::GET("https://cran.rstudio.com/") and see if Status is 200.

Comment: Also try downloading the package from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/lmerTest_3.1-2.tar.gz and installing from Tools > Install Packages, change "Install From" to Package Archive File and select the package downloaded

Comment: Do you get the same errors when you run R from the console?

Comment: @Mohanasundaram when I run httr::GET("cran.rstudio.com/"), I get Error: package ‘httr’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it

Comment: Also, I forgot to say, I'm using Windows 10

Comment: @Mohanasundaram, I'm not really sure how to try your second suggestion, when I change to Package Archive File and try to load lmerTests, for instance, there are multiple folders and files for that package, but I can only select 1?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I got similar errors saying I couldn't connect to the CRAN mirror today in R console today, though yesterday R was working while RStudio was not, so I'm confused by that...

Comment: save the downloaded package in a folder and run install.packages("{#path to the folder}/lmerTest_3.1-2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

Comment: Thanks @Mohanasundaram, I couldn't get that code to work, but it's a problem with mutliple different packages, not just lmerTest. See next comment for error codes:

Comment: >install.packages("{C:\Users\nwr\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\lmerTest}/lmerTest_3.1-2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""{C:\U"
> install.packages("C:\Users\nwr\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\lmerTest/lmerTest_3.1-2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
> install.packages("C:\Users\nwr\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\lmerTest\lmerTest_3.1-2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"

Comment: use forward slash / instead of \

Comment: download the package and save it in D: drive if you have id and run install.packages("D:/lmerTest_3.1-2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

Comment: It is to check whether the problem is with the installation of package or the connection. If it is getting installed, we could be sure that the problem is with the connection.

Comment: Thanks @Mohanasundaram, rookie mistake with the forward vs back slash!

Comment: That code worked and lmerTest loaded correctly, so it looks like a connection problem

Comment: run curl::has_internet() and check if it is TRUE.

Comment: I hope you are not using proxy and your firewall is not blocking R and RStudio

Comment: TRUE in RStudio and console

Comment: @Mohanasundaram, re firewall: I don't think so, everything is working fine on another computer using the same network

Comment: I tried turning the firewall off - it did not fix the problem

Comment: I am still trying to figure out what else could block the connection to the repository.

Comment: @Mohanasundaram me too! Thanks for all your suggestions so far. I'm leaving my desk now but will check any further responses when I get back in a day or so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, after 4 phone calls and multiple attempts at fixing this problem, my institutional IT department were today able to disable the antivirus block that was preventing R and R Studio from working.

Apparently, to avoid this in the future, I need to run new programs from a specific folder. So it was the antivirus after all, but I couldn't change the settings from my end as I have a work computer.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue. I recevied the following error on startup

> `Error in tools::startDynamicHelp() : internet routines cannot be loaded`

After investigation, I found my antivirus software has quarantined `R-4.0.0/modules/x64/internet.dll`. Unfortunately, my antivirus settings are controlled by group policy so I can't disable them to claim a solution.

Comment: Yep, can confirm that is a problem.

As a solution for now, what worked for me is using the x64 internet.dll from a previous 3.6.1 installation and copy it to R-4.0.0/modules/x64/
Alternatively, select in RStudio the x86 if x64 is not needed

Comment: Copying the internet.dll solved the issue for now. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I fixed that by simply running [each time]:

`options(download.file.method="wget")`

Answer (score 2):

i can confirm that modules\x64\internet.dll quarantined by symantec in my work pc.  that is the main problem.  I will ring my IT to fix and update the outcome here.

Comment: not symantec, it is protect cylance antivirus quarantine it

Comment: my IT guy told me that internet.dll is a virus and they will go to consult cylance antivirus company.  i said to him that i did not think so.  i will update this when i get back answers from cylance.  cheers.

Comment: my IT guy gave me to use R 3.6.1 which he is confident that it is clean

Answer (score 0):

> **Install RStudio and R Version With help of IT Team.**
>
> **Download** New Version of **R** from **CRAN**
>
> **Copy** an `internet.dll` file `(which Size should be Up to 5MB)` from Existing Version Installed by IT Team on Your System
>
> `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3\modules\x64` and
>
> **Paste** it to `C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\R\R-4.1.2\modules\x64` folder of New version
>
> Then `Restart RStudio` you will not get any **error**
>
> also you can `install any packages`
>
> Do not need to make changes into any File like `Rprofile and Renv`
>
> Or any other `Options()` Functions
>
> `Note: The File Path may be different in your System`