# R: "internet routines cannot be loaded" when starting from RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 8.5 with Linux kernel 4.18 and Gnome 3.32.2. In this system, I've got R 4.1.2 compiled with the tool [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) with *shared libraries enabled*. On top of that, I installed RStudio 2021.09.01-372 from an [RPM from the official RStudio website](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download).

When I start Rstudio, the first line of output after the usual R startup is an error:

```
Error in tools::startDynamicHelp() : internet routines cannot be loaded
```

I am unable to figure out what's causing this error, and with it I can't run things like refresh CRAN or update packages. But *if I start a pure R session from the terminal (instead of Rstudio) this error does not occur*.

Some things I tried:

[Install the `krb5` and `libssh2` packages](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/4421) on my host system: Didn't help.

Starting a "pure" R session (both with and without the `--vanilla` argument) from the Terminal tab *within* Rstudio also gives this error. If I try to run `update.packages()` from this session, it pops up a window to select a CRAN mirror then fails with the following:

```
Warning: failed to download mirrors file (internet routines cannot be loaded); using local file '/home/[my username]/.asdf/installs/R/4.1.2/lib64/R/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  internet routines cannot be loaded
Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  unable to load shared object '/home/penyuan/.asdf/installs/R/4.1.2/lib64/R/modules//internet.so':
  /lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined symbol: EVP_KDF_ctrl, version OPENSSL_1_1_1b
```

But like I said, the strange thing is if I start an R session *outside* of Rstudio, these errors don't happen.

Within RStudio, the only workaround I can find is to run this command upon startup (suggested in [this thread](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4904#issuecomment-804032753)):

```
options(download.file.method="wget")
```

Once this is done, everything else seems to work, such as package updates.

However, I don't want to manually do this every time I start RStudio. So I tried to put it into `~/.Rprofile` including a test `print()` as follows:

```
print("This is `~/.Rprofile`")
options(download.file.method="wget")
```

When I open RStudio, I can see the output from the `print()` call, but the `options()` command is *not* run because the original error shows up again. I still have to manually enter `options(download.file.method="wget")` every time.

I also tried to fold everything into a `.First` function in `~/.Rprofile` as follows:

```
.First <- function() {
    options(download.file.method="wget")
    print("This is the `.First` function in `~/.Rprofile`")
}
```

Unfortunately, same result as before: `print()`'s output is seen, but `options()` is not run.

I also made sure that my `~/.Rprofile` includes a trailing newline [as discussed here](https://yihui.org/en/2018/04/rprofile-trailing-newline/). But this didn't help.

The above are the steps I've tried so far.

Why does this error only occur when running RStudio or a terminal within Rstudio? Why doesn't it happen if I start R from a terminal outside of Rstudio?

*Is there a way to solve the problem so that the error doesn't happen in the first place*? If it can't be solved, how do I set up my `~/.Rprofile` so that `options(download.file.method="wget")` will be run?

Thank you.

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61555543/unable-to-install-packages-after-r-update-unable-to-access-index-for-repository) potentially shed some light on your issue?

Comment: @DanielMolitor thank you, but no. That thread suggests (1) checking antivirus which is not applicable in my case; and (2) one answer suggests `options(download.file.method="wget")` which I already discussed in my question.